# Flattening complex repeating structure in biztalk

Tags: c#, dictionary, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I´ve an xml instance similar to this:

```
<outerElementList>
   <outerElement>
       <outerID>1</outerID>
       <outerName>test1</outerName>
       <innerElementList>
           <innerElement>
               <innerID>10</innerID>
               <innerName>test10</innerName>
           </innerElement>
           <innerElement>
               <innerID>20</innerID>
               <innerName>test20</innerName>
           </innerElement>
       </innerElementList>
   </outerElement>
   <outerElement>
       <outerID>2</outerID>
       <outerName>test2</outerName>
       <innerElementList>
           <innerElement>
               <innerID>30</innerID>
               <innerName>test30</innerName>
           </innerElement>
           <innerElement>
               <innerID>40</innerID>
               <innerName>test40</innerName>
           </innerElement>
       </innerElementList>
   </outerElement>
```

And I need to end up with something like this:

```
<ElementList>
   <Element>
       <ID>1</ID>
       <Name>test1</Name>          
   </Element>
   <Element>
       <ID>2</ID>
       <Name>test2</Name>              
   </Element>
   <Element>
       <ID>10</ID>
        <SuperID>1</SuperID>
       <Name>test10</Name>         
   </Element>
   <Element>
       <ID>20</ID>
       <SuperID>1</SuperID>            
       <Name>test20</Name> 
   </Element>
   <Element>
       <ID>30</ID> 
       <SuperID>2</SuperID>
       <Name>test30</Name> 
   </Element>
   <Element>
       <ID>40</ID> 
       <SuperID>2</SuperID>
       <Name>test40</Name> 
   </Element>
```

SuperID of an inner element being the ID og the enclosing outer element. 
I realize that I need to use the looping functoid, but I cant seem to get i right.

**This question is a spinoff off  [22035260](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22035260/flattening-repeating-structure-in-biztalk)**
basvo provided a great answer to the original question, where both the inner and outer structure only consisted of a single ID. Unfortunately it isnt easily applied to a more complex structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you will probably need to do is create an intermediate schema with two record types and two maps.  The first map is shown below.

[image: Intermediate map]

This results in the below XML.

```
<ElementList>
  <ElementRoot>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>test1</Name>
  </ElementRoot>
  <ElementRoot>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Name>test2</Name>
  </ElementRoot>
  <Element>
    <ID>10</ID>
    <SuperID>1</SuperID>
    <Name>test10</Name>
  </Element>
  <Element>
    <ID>20</ID>
    <SuperID>1</SuperID>
    <Name>test20</Name>
  </Element>
  <Element>
    <ID>30</ID>
    <SuperID>2</SuperID>
    <Name>test30</Name>
  </Element>
  <Element>
    <ID>40</ID>
    <SuperID>2</SuperID>
    <Name>test40</Name>
  </Element>
</ElementList>
```

Then this is easily mapped

[image: Second Map]

Resulting in

```
<ElementList>
  <Element>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>test1</Name>
  </Element>
  <Element>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Name>test2</Name>
  </Element>
  <Element>
    <ID>10</ID>
    <SuperID>1</SuperID>
    <Name>test10</Name>
  </Element>
  <Element>
    <ID>20</ID>
    <SuperID>1</SuperID>
    <Name>test20</Name>
  </Element>
  <Element>
    <ID>30</ID>
    <SuperID>2</SuperID>
    <Name>test30</Name>
  </Element>
  <Element>
    <ID>40</ID>
    <SuperID>2</SuperID>
    <Name>test40</Name>
  </Element>
</ElementList>
```

Note: The other option would of course be to do it via Custom XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Dijkgraafs very competent answer, this is how we solved the problem using XSLT.

```
<ftns17:outerElementList xmlns:ftns17="http://[Parent-Scheme]" xmlns:ftns19="http://[Element-Scheme]">
  <xsl:for-each select="/*[local-name() = 'Parent']/*[local-name() = 'outerElementList'][1]/*[local-name() = 'outerElement']">
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="*[local-name() = 'ID']/text()" />
    <ftns17:outerElement>
      <ftns19:ID>
        <xsl:value-of select="$id" />
      </ftns19:ID>
      <ftns19:Name>
        <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name() = 'Name']/text()" />
      </ftns19:Name>
    </ftns17:outerElement>
    <xsl:for-each select="*[local-name() = 'innerElementList']/*[local-name() = 'innerElement']">
      <ftns17:innerElement>
        <ftns19:ID>
          <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name() = 'ID']/text()" />
        </ftns19:ID>
        <ftns19:SuperID>
          <xsl:value-of select="$id" />
        </ftns19:SuperID>
        <ftns19:Name>
          <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name() = 'Name']/text()" />
        </ftns19:Name>      
    </ftns17:innerElement>    
  </xsl:for-each>  
</xsl:for-each>
</ftns17:outerElementList>
```

Using inline XSLT in a scripting functoid and attaching the output to the elementlist.